# Do I need to use clearTimeout() and set the timeout to null in this problem?

Tags: javascript, timeout

I was going through this example of 'debouncing' a function (calling it only after a certain time interval had passed):

```
Function.prototype.myDebounce = function(interval) {
  let timeout;
  return (...args) => {
    const functionCall = () => {
      timeout = null;
      this(...args);
    };
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(functionCall, interval);
  }
};
```

And I'm a little confused as to why we need to use both `clearTimeout()` and `timeout = null` here. From my research, I found that `clearTimeout()` actually clears the timer, so why do I need the additional `timeout = null` in the function that actually makes the function call? I tried experimenting with the code, and it seems to do exactly the same thing even when I take `timeout = null` out.

NOTE: Another explanation of `clearTimeout()` stated that it stops a function from running; is that also correct?

Comment: No, it's not needed - as setTimeout's return value is a primitive anyway, nothing substantial is saved here. I'd suggest checking implementation of `debounce` in lodash - while obviously far more sophisticated, it shows the primary mechanism in quite good details.

Comment: @raina77ow Ah ok, would be there be any reason/advantage for why they chose to also include the `timer = null` in the `functionCall` function?

Comment: Without knowing who 'they' are it's pretty hard to tell. :) Maybe the initial implementation had some checks for `timeout` value and didn't call clearTimeout if it was null in attempt to optimize this or so.

Comment: Here's [lodash debounce current implementation](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/15e1557b2a97c8bbee22d873832d90ed3ba50ba7/debounce.js)